# Current sensing application

Tags: transistors, adc, zener, dac, current-sensing

[image: Schematic of the circuit]

The purpose of the application is to maintain a constant current at the load, even if the resistance changes.

I understand that the ADC is reporting the voltage and current values at the load to the micro controller. Also, that the load voltage is being measured by the differential amplifier (U4) and the current is being measured by the current-shunt monitor (U7), set up for low-side detection. 
Please correct me if I'm wrong on any of this.

I believe the DAC is keeping the current constant by suppling a voltage to the positive terminal of op-amp (U6). Since the curr_out is a voltage value it also fed into the other terminal and I believe this difference is driving the gate of the transistor.

Yet, how does this keep the current constant at the load? Furthermore, why is there a zener diode between LOAD+ and LOAD-?

Also,is the 23V above the load, supplying the current while the transistor is working to keep is constant from the difference in DAC_OUT and Curr_out?

I just can't seem to rap my head around how this works?

A4V5 is 4.5V

Answer (score 0):

The circuit keeps constant current because U7, U6, and transistor Q1 form a control loop with deep negative feedback. It is a standard linear regulator. The current level is defined by DAC output, Iout = DAC_OUT/500. If any deviation in current occur, the amplifier U6 will act to compensate/negate this deviation. All this is actually written on the schematics, with details on sensitivities and conversion ratios. The Zener is likely for protection against some spikes in the "load".

Comment: Thanks. How do you know Iout = DAC_OUT/500? Also do you happen to know why the zener diode is set up in reverse bias?

Comment: "How do you know ..." probably from "Current Sensor Notes" right there on the schematic. Also note that any time you disconnect a load from a current source, it'll try to maintain constant current by cranking the voltage up as close to infinity as it can. Which is where the zener comes in.

Comment: @ZachStow, the Zener is connected in a very standard way, this is how it works, on reverse breakdown branch of its I-V curve. The Zener with flowing current makes a typical voltage stabilizer, so the output voltage on load terminals won't exceed Zener's nominal value, and will prevent the current source to go all the way to  to ground exposing the load to full 23V of main power rail, as Brian commented.

Comment: @ZachStow, regarding the Iout, I simply reversed their formula. However, there is a mistake in that schematics: the INA301A2 has a gain of 50. So either their formula is incorrect, or the U7 part should be listed as INA301A1.